# SharePoint performance optimization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, performance

I'm trying to optimize SharePoint performance, like Response Time of web requests. I have FE hosts on which are installed IIS+SP. They receive requests and communicate with BE WCFs hosts. From monitoring tools, I see that behaviour:

1. A web request arrives at FE (say at time T = 0 ms).
2. IIS immediately gets it and starts a Synchronous Invocation to local SharePoint (e.g. at T = 0.12 ms).
3. 90% of the times, before SP starts elaborating the request there is a consistent wait. For example, at T = 6338.70 ms.
4. The request is then usually served quite fast (SP, then WCF calls, etc..) and end at T = 6677.25 ms.

At the end, the Response Time of this request was 6.6 seconds, 6.3 of which spent "waiting to be served by SP on local FE host". There are of course worst cases, where request waits one or two minutes.

Currently I'm tuning .NET Frameworks config files like machine.config and aspnet.config. Do parameters like maxconnection, maxWorkerThreads, maxIoThreads, minFreeThreads, minLocalRequestFreeThreads, maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU, requestQueueLimit and so on have an impact on SP performance? I think so since SP is based on ASP.NET, right? Or does SP have its own config files to be tuned? I found nothing googling.

I'm not a SP dev, nor the mantainer of these SP services, I have just basic knowledge, so I hope this makes sense.
Thank you

Comment: You'd need to open a support case to see about supportability for adjusting those values as it isn't documented. That said, using the Dashboard Designer is a good way to determine what is stalling if your page times are >3 seconds. Often when load times are high, when working with webpart pages, you might see a bunch of content rollup webparts. Those can hurt performance as SharePoint must query the content where the webparts are pointing to. Anyhow, there are more SharePoint-specific things to adjust (BLOB Cache, Ouput Cache, SQL perf, etc.) before looking at anything lower level.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Thanks for tips. Is the Dashboard Designer present in SP 2007? I asked and we have already BLOB Cache active. We are working on other kinds of cache.